# Sign confusion in the energy-momentum tensor for the Klein-Gordon scalar field in Wald's General Relativity

Tags: metric-tensor, field-theory, conventions, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, textbook-erratum

In Wald's book General Relativity, Wald gives the energy-momentum tensor of the scalar field that leads to the Klein-Gordon equation,
$$
\begin{align}
T_{\mu\nu}
=\phi_{,\mu}\phi_{,\nu}-\frac{1}{2}\eta_{\mu\nu}\left(\phi_{,\sigma}\phi^{,\sigma}+m^2\phi^2\right),\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
wherein I used the notation $\phi_{,\mu}:=\partial_\mu\phi$. Eq. (1) is eq. (4.2.20) on p. 63; Wald uses the $(-1,+1,+1,+1)$ convention for the Minkowski metric. The Lagrangian density of the real free and massive scalar field that satisfies the Klein-Gordon equation using said metric convention is given by,
$$
\begin{align}
\mathcal{L}=-\frac{1}{2}\phi_{,\sigma}\phi^{,\sigma}-\frac{1}{2}m^2\phi^2=-\frac{1}{2}\phi_{,\sigma}\phi^{,\sigma}-V(\phi).\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
The former expression can also be found on p. 451 as Eq. (E.1.6).
We now write Eq. (1) as,
$$
\begin{align}
T_{\mu\nu}
=\phi_{,\mu}\phi_{,\nu}+\eta_{\mu\nu}\mathcal{L}.\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$
The energy-momentum tensor with raised indices can be obtained from Eq. (3),
$$
\begin{align}
T^{\mu\nu}
=\eta^{\mu\sigma}\eta^{\nu\rho}T_{\sigma\rho}=\phi^{,\mu}\phi^{,\nu}+\eta^{\mu\sigma}\eta^{\nu\rho}\eta_{\sigma\rho}\mathcal{L}
=\eta^{\mu\sigma}\eta^{\nu\rho}T_{\sigma\rho}=\phi^{,\mu}\phi^{,\nu}+\eta^{\mu\nu}\mathcal{L}.\tag{4}
\end{align}
$$
From now on, we will refer to the energy-momentum tensor of the Klein-Gordon scalar field as represented in Eq. (4).

Okay, so now get to the actual confusion. In the appendix, Wald derives the energy-momentum tensor in eq. (E.1.36)
$$
\begin{align}
T^{\mu\nu}=\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial(\phi_{,\mu})}\phi^{,\nu}-\eta^{\mu\nu}\mathcal{L}\tag{5}
\end{align}
$$
from Noether's theorem on p. 457 and calls it the *canonical* energy-momentum tensor. Let us first evaluate,
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial(\phi_{,\mu})}
=-\frac{1}{2}\eta^{\sigma\rho}\frac{\partial(\phi_{,\sigma}\phi_{,\rho})}{\partial(\phi_{,\mu})}
=-\frac{1}{2}\eta^{\sigma\rho}\delta_{\sigma\mu}\phi_{,\sigma}-\frac{1}{2}\eta^{\sigma\rho}\delta_{\sigma\rho}\phi_{,\rho}
=-\phi^{,\mu},
\tag{6}
\end{align}
$$
and insert Eq. (6) into (5). We find,
$$
\begin{align}
T^{\mu\nu}=-\phi^{,\mu}\phi^{,\nu}-\eta^{\mu\nu}\mathcal{L}.
\tag{7}
\end{align}
$$
**It is obvious that Eq. (7) does not equal (4)**, however, both equations *only* differ by a sign.

Can it be that the sign difference has something to do with [Does metric signature affect the stress energy tensor?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/228185/)

**If not, how can one explain the sign difference?**

Comment: related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/335785/226902 and https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/619659/226902

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OP is right: Wald's book has a sign mistake in eq. (E.1.36).

Comment: See also https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/681539/226902