# How to define energy density and pressure for a scalar condensate?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, pressure, field-theory, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

Consider a scalar field theory in flat spacetime whose Lagrangian reads
$$\mathcal{L}=\frac{1}{2}\eta^{\mu\nu}(\partial_\mu\varphi)\partial_\nu\varphi-V(\varphi).$$
Then the energy-momentum tensor reads (we use the signature (+,-,-,-))
$$T^{\mu\nu}=(\partial^\mu\varphi)\partial^\nu\varphi-\eta^{\mu\nu}\mathcal{L}.\tag{1}$$
Now we want to define the energy density and pressure for a scalar condensate from the above energy-momentum tensor. In Weinberg's book "Cosmology'', he defines these quantities as follows.

Comparing Eq.(1) with the energy-momentum tensor for a perfect fluid,
$$T^{\mu\nu}=(\rho+p)u^\mu u^\nu-\eta^{\mu\nu}p,$$
one may identify
$$p=\frac{1}{2}\eta^{\mu\nu}(\partial_\mu\varphi)\partial_\nu\varphi-V(\varphi),\tag{2}$$
$$\rho=\frac{1}{2}\eta^{\mu\nu}(\partial_\mu\varphi)\partial_\nu\varphi+V(\varphi),\tag{3}$$
and
$$u^\mu=\left(\eta^{\rho\sigma}\partial_\rho\varphi\partial_\sigma\varphi\right)^{-1/2}\partial^\mu\varphi.$$

However, there are some problems with the above definitions.

(i) The first problem is that, according to Eq. (3), one has
$$\rho=\frac{1}{2}\dot{\varphi}^2-\frac{1}{2}(\nabla\varphi)^2+V(\varphi).$$
Why the gradient energy has a negative contribution to the energy density?

(ii) The definitions are only valid for
$$\eta^{\rho\sigma}\partial_\rho\varphi\partial_\sigma\varphi\geq 0.$$
What if $\eta^{\rho\sigma}\partial_\rho\varphi\partial_\sigma\varphi<0$? Can't we define the energy density and pressure for a scalar condensate which is, say, space-dependent but time-independent?

With the above two problems, I would think that the definitions (2) and (3) are problematic. Then how to define in general the energy density and pressure for a scalar condensate?

Answer (score 1):

There's a mistake in your formulae (2) and (3).  You should start from (1) and the following (for an isotropic field, since you want pressure of a perfect isotropic fluid):
\begin{align}\tag{1}
\rho &= T_{00}, &p &= T_{11} = T_{22} = T_{33}.
\end{align}
Then (notice the + sign in front of the squared gradient) $$\tag{2}
\rho = (\partial_0 \phi)^2 - \mathcal{L} = \frac{1}{2} \, \dot{\phi}^2 + \frac{1}{2} (\nabla \phi)^2 + \mathcal{V}(\phi).
$$
If the field is isotropic *everywhere*, then $\nabla \phi = 0$.  The *isotropic pressure* is (with $\nabla \phi = 0$):
$$\tag{3}
p = T_{11} = \mathcal{L} = \frac{1}{2} \, \dot{\phi}^2 - \mathcal{V}(\phi).
$$

Comment: But how can I justify Eq. (1) in your answer? Your Eq. (1) is obtained from the expression of the energy-momentum tensor of perfect fluid when choosing $u^{\mu}=(1,0,0,0)$. How do you know these relations are valid in general for a scalar field?

Comment: And yes, I originally used your expressions but when I look into Weinberg's book, I realized subtleties, although I am not convinced by Weinberg's definitions.

Comment: @WeinEld, the scalar field may be in any other states (not necessarily isotropic).  If its state isn't isotropic, then it may not act as a perfect fluid (and the four-velocity that you gave may even be spacelike!).  The homogeneous (and isotropic) state implies the above relations.